# save .waw sound into a variable

Tags: c#, winforms

i would like to ask how can I save waw sound into a variable. In program i have 3 buttons and when a click I want to play a different sound. Now I got it like that

```
`SoundPlayer playDeath = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.death);
 playDeath.Play();`
```

I tried to save the audio to a variable and play but it did not work.

```
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer ();
 Bitmap sound; 
 sound = Properties.Resources.death; 
 player.Play(sound);
```

Is there any way to do that by clicking the button to save Variables sound. For example

```
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer ();
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               sound = Properties.Resources.death; 
               player.Play(sound);
          }

   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               sound = Properties.Resources.levelUp; 
               player.Play(sound);
          }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the appropriate variable type for the resource you are working with. In case of a .wav file a Bitmap is certainly not the correct type. You probably want to use `System.IO.Stream` as the type:

```
System.IO.Stream sound = Properties.Resources.death;
player.Play(sound);
```